# I am writing my first Android app and I am suddenly getting pages and pages of error messages that I can't make head or tail of

Tags: android

The game is supposed to read items in from an array and then display text boxes to the user to guess the letters of the word. All went fine until I added in the line lr2.addView(edT); I am not sure why or what went wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. By the way, I made sure everything was updated, etc.

```
package com.example.riva.fruitguessinggame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

String fruits[] = {"apple", "lemon", "peach", "melon", "banana", "orange"};
char letters[];
String fruit;
EditText edT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams edtTxtLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    edtTxtLayout.setMargins(5, 5, 10, 5);

    LinearLayout lr1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout lr2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);

    // First row with instructions.
    tv1.setText("Guess the name of the fruit by filling in the boxes.");
    tv1.setTextSize(16f);
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    tv1.setPadding(5,5,5,10);
    lr1.addView(tv1);

    // Choose a random fruit from the array
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(fruits.length);
    fruit = (fruits[idx]);

    edT = new EditText(this.getApplicationContext());

    // Loop through the item, creating a text box for each letter, second row
    for(int i=0; i<fruit.length(); i++){
        edT.setId(i);
        edT.setTextSize(20f);
        edT.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        edT.setEms(2);
        edT.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        edT.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
        edT.setLayoutParams(edtTxtLayout);
        edT.setOnClickListener(this);
        lr2.addView(edT);

        // Read the letters of the fruit name into an array
        letters = fruit.toCharArray();

    }

    lr2.setGravity(1);

    ll.addView(lr1);
    ll.addView(lr2);

    setContentView(ll);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    checkLetter();
}

private void checkLetter() {
    int a = edT.getId();


}
```

}

The error messages are:

```
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
06-26 14:32:27.150    2342-2483/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay S
06-26 14:32:27.170    2342-2580/? E/SecCamera-JNI-Java﹕ SecCamera.open()
06-26 14:32:27.175    2342-2580/? E/SecCamera-JNI-Java﹕ SecCamera()
06-26 14:32:27.395    1933-1933/? E/ISecCameraHardware﹕ FocusMode=infinity, PrevFocusMode=infinity
06-26 14:32:27.395    1933-2330/? E/ISecCameraHardware﹕ preview window is NULL!
06-26 14:32:27.545    2342-7910/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ Listener does not implements SmartFaceInfoListener2
06-26 14:32:27.720    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage start : prev time [ 117920485 ]
06-26 14:32:27.910    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage end : function time [ 188584 ] [-1]
06-26 14:32:27.910    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage start : prev time [ 189523 ]
06-26 14:32:27.910    2342-7910/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay onInfo: 100: 0
06-26 14:32:28.040    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage end : function time [ 127923 ] [-1]
06-26 14:32:28.040    2342-7910/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay onInfo: 100: 0
06-26 14:32:28.205    2342-2483/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay X: false
06-26 14:32:36.160    2342-2482/? E/SEC PowerHAL﹕ sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or directory
06-26 14:32:36.160    2342-2482/? E/SEC PowerHAL﹕ sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input8/enabled: No such file or directory
06-26 14:32:36.985    2809-2809/? E/NfcService﹕ callback == null
06-26 14:32:41.315    2342-2459/? E/KeyguardHostView﹕ KeyguardHostView()
06-26 14:32:41.605    2342-2459/? E/KeyguardShortcutView﹕ density = 320
06-26 14:32:41.840    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:32:41.840    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:32:41.840    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:32:41.840    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:32:41.850    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:32:41.850    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:32:41.850    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:32:41.850    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:35:11.780    6232-6377/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [b] __PingReply__
06-26 14:35:17.365    7943-7943/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.android.email.service.s.a
06-26 14:35:17.370    7943-7943/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.android.email.service.s.b
06-26 14:35:17.730    7943-7967/? E/Gmail﹕ Error finding the version of the Email provider.....
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.email
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:103)
        at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.a(SourceFile:1279)
        at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:219)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-26 14:38:34.075    6232-6232/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
06-26 14:40:34.050    1930-2015/? E/SecTVOutService﹕ virtual void android::SecTVOutService::setHdmiStatus(uint32_t)::mSecHdmi.connect() fail
06-26 14:40:34.060    2342-2482/? E/SEC PowerHAL﹕ sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or directory
06-26 14:40:34.070    2342-2482/? E/SEC PowerHAL﹕ sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input8/enabled: No such file or directory
06-26 14:40:35.050    2738-2898/? E/GLThread﹕ create surface
06-26 14:40:35.190    2809-2809/? E/NfcService﹕ callback == null
06-26 14:40:35.385    2823-2823/? E/Launcher﹕ Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
06-26 14:40:35.490    2342-4427/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:40:35.525    2809-2809/? E/NfcService﹕ callback == null
06-26 14:40:35.800    8037-8102/? E/notifySoException﹕ [kinfoc][8102] JNI_OnLoad env=0x57fd46c0
06-26 14:40:35.800    8037-8102/? E/notifySoException﹕ [kinfoc][8102] LoadCrashHandler succeed
06-26 14:40:36.185    2342-2816/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:40:36.295    8037-8126/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
06-26 14:40:36.840    8037-8037/? E/﹕ Device driver API match
Device driver API version: 23
User space API version: 23
06-26 14:40:36.840    8037-8037/? E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013
06-26 14:40:39.570    2342-4427/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:40:40.780    2823-2823/? E/Launcher﹕ Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
06-26 14:40:41.080    2809-2809/? E/Parcel﹕ Reading a NULL string not supported here.
06-26 14:40:41.095    2342-2721/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:40:41.160    8185-8231/? E/notifySoException﹕ [kinfoc][8231] JNI_OnLoad env=0x4000fa48
06-26 14:40:41.170    8185-8231/? E/notifySoException﹕ [kinfoc][8231] LoadCrashHandler succeed
06-26 14:40:41.305    2738-2898/? E/GLThread﹕ create surface
06-26 14:40:41.795    8185-8267/? E/SYSCORE﹕ [virusengine][8267] LoadCrashHandler succeed
06-26 14:40:44.210    2342-2470/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
06-26 14:40:52.290    2823-2823/? E/Launcher﹕ Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
06-26 14:40:52.325    2738-2898/? E/GLThread﹕ create surface
06-26 14:40:53.610    2835-2835/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
06-26 14:40:53.610    2835-2835/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-26 14:40:54.080    8500-8512/? E/SPPClientService﹕ ============PushLog. commonIsShipBuild. stop!
06-26 14:40:54.080    8500-8512/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [PushClientApplication] Push log off : This is Ship build version
06-26 14:40:54.405    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method b.a
06-26 14:40:54.475    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method b.a
06-26 14:40:54.555    2342-2470/? E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-26 14:40:54.560    2342-2342/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:40:54.595    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method b.a
06-26 14:40:54.625    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method b.a
06-26 14:40:54.625    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method b.a
06-26 14:40:54.630    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method b.a
06-26 14:40:54.695    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method b.a
06-26 14:40:54.710    8515-8515/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method b.b
06-26 14:40:55.325    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.330    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput$Builder', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.345    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.375    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Action$Builder', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.390    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.390    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.390    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.390    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.400    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.RemoteInput[]', referenced from method f.a
06-26 14:40:55.420    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.transition.Transition', referenced from method f.b
06-26 14:40:55.430    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.hangouts.telephony.TeleConnectionService', referenced from method f.i
06-26 14:40:55.430    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telecom.TelecomManager', referenced from method f.k
06-26 14:40:55.545    8536-8556/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: mmsconfig
06-26 14:40:55.555    8536-8556/? E/Babel﹕ canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
06-26 14:40:55.585    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telecom.PhoneAccount$Builder', referenced from method cqf.e
06-26 14:40:55.585    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telecom.TelecomManager', referenced from method cqf.g
06-26 14:40:55.620    8536-8536/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.libraries.hangouts.video.ScreenCaptureVideoSource$2', referenced from method com.google.android.libraries.hangouts.video.ScreenCaptureVideoSource.<init>
06-26 14:40:57.415    2835-2835/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
06-26 14:40:57.415    2835-2835/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-26 14:40:59.855    8815-8827/? E/SPPClientService﹕ ============PushLog. commonIsShipBuild. stop!
06-26 14:40:59.855    8815-8827/? E/SPPClientService﹕ [PushClientApplication] Push log off : This is Ship build version
06-26 14:40:59.930    2835-2835/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
06-26 14:41:00.010    8624-8624/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.telecom.TelecomManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.y.a
06-26 14:41:00.090    2778-4155/? E/MDM﹕ [67] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
06-26 14:42:45.510    2342-2483/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay S
06-26 14:42:45.530    2342-2580/? E/SecCamera-JNI-Java﹕ SecCamera.open()
06-26 14:42:45.530    2342-2580/? E/SecCamera-JNI-Java﹕ SecCamera()
06-26 14:42:45.865    1933-2330/? E/ISecCameraHardware﹕ FocusMode=infinity, PrevFocusMode=infinity
06-26 14:42:45.865    1933-2331/? E/ISecCameraHardware﹕ preview window is NULL!
06-26 14:42:46.010    2342-8846/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ Listener does not implements SmartFaceInfoListener2
06-26 14:42:46.195    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage start : prev time [ 618282716 ]
06-26 14:42:46.455    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage end : function time [ 260730 ] [-1]
06-26 14:42:46.455    2342-8846/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay onInfo: 100: 0
06-26 14:42:46.455    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage start : prev time [ 261363 ]
06-26 14:42:46.570    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage end : function time [ 114892 ] [-1]
06-26 14:42:46.570    2342-8846/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay onInfo: 100: 0
06-26 14:42:46.570    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage start : prev time [ 115594 ]
06-26 14:42:46.700    2342-2582/? E/SmartScreen_JNI﹕ processImage end : function time [ 131092 ] [-1]
06-26 14:42:46.755    2342-2483/? E/SmartFaceManager﹕ checkForSmartStay X: false
06-26 14:42:54.490    2342-2482/? E/SEC PowerHAL﹕ sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or directory
06-26 14:42:54.490    2342-2482/? E/SEC PowerHAL﹕ sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input8/enabled: No such file or directory
06-26 14:42:54.960    2809-2809/? E/NfcService﹕ callback == null
06-26 14:42:59.710    2342-2459/? E/KeyguardHostView﹕ KeyguardHostView()
06-26 14:43:00.035    2342-2459/? E/KeyguardShortcutView﹕ density = 320
06-26 14:43:00.210    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:43:00.210    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:43:00.210    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:43:00.210    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:43:00.380    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:43:00.380    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:43:00.380    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:43:00.380    2342-2459/? E/LSO﹕ LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
06-26 14:46:35.515    8885-8885/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.android.email.service.s.a
06-26 14:46:35.515    8885-8885/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.android.email.service.s.b
06-26 14:46:36.000    8885-8922/? E/Gmail﹕ Error finding the version of the Email provider.....
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.email
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:103)
        at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.a(SourceFile:1279)
        at com.google.android.gm.EmailMigrationService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:219)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-26 14:49:28.000    1930-2015/? E/SecTVOutService﹕ virtual void android::SecTVOutService::setHdmiStatus(uint32_t)::mSecHdmi.connect() fail
06-26 14:49:28.015    2342-2482/? E/SEC PowerHAL﹕ sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or directory
```

I got an error message that my post contains too many characters, so if there is a need, I can post more of the error messages in another post. Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: These logs are not issues for your app. Its the log that is generated by other apps and android OS. Is your app stopping with an error message?

Comment: Which IDE are you using, Android Studio or Eclipse ?

Comment: always start from start...http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Comment: I am writing using Android Studio and testing on a Samsung Galaxy SIII, but tried using Genymotion too. Got the same errors on Genymotion.

Comment: The app just says "Fruit Guessing Game has stopped working" or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, Karan. I will check out this link.

Comment: I have tried all of these options and the only way I can get this to run is to remove the line lr2.addView(edT); in the loop. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I am writing a new app now and I keep getting these errors. I am my wit's end. Is there something I can do on my phone? (The new app is a paint-type app - from a tutorial.) I tried filtering it to errors only and to "show only selected applications". The fact that it is happening again makes me think it is the phone and not the code. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The logs show every event that is happening on your device. These contain logs from your app and the ones from other apps and services that are currently running on the device.

If you are using Android Studio, you can filter which logs logcat should display. As seen in the image below, you can select the app you are running (1), and the option that only logs created by this app should be shown (2)

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Comment: I will try this, but I got the same errors when trying to run the app on Genymotion. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are now just looking at the logs for all apps running on the device, and they will just output whatever they want. Try setting the logcat filter to something that will only show your own app's output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try and filter it by app.

Comment: I have set it to "Show only selected application" but I still get pages of error messages. Should I toss this and start again?

Answer (score 0):

## LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

provide width and height ,